# <script> not working in angular 5 components (Plaid Link with Angular 2+)

Tags: jquery, angular, plaid

I'm trying to use Plaid Link inside of an Angular Web App. It seems that the script provided by plaid only works inside the `<body>` of the index.html file. When I try to use it in a component the script simply does not run.

I'm following along with the documentation at https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#step-2-simple-integration

They have some jquery code that works fine if I make just a basic html file with it inside but doesn't work inside of an angular component/

Here is an example of code that wont work in angular?

```
`<form id='plaid-link-form'></form>
<script
src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"
data-client-name="My App"
data-form-id="plaid-link-form"
data-key="[PUBLIC KEY]"
data-product="auth"
data-env="sandbox">
</script>`
```

EDIT: I've made a mistake. I use Angular 5, not 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an Ionic 2 (Angular2+) use of the plaid link in this repository.
https://github.com/pbernasconi/plaid-link-ionic-2-example/tree/master/src
I added the script to the index and then run it in a controller. I don't exactly understand how the declarations.d.ts file comes into play but I have a file with the same code in it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **system.js**, try importing the script using `system.js`'s `import` function as below:-

```
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(){
    System.import('https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js').then(Plaid => {
      var handler = Plaid.create({
        clientName: 'My App',
        env: 'sandbox',
        key: '[PUBLIC_KEY]', // Replace with your public_key to test with live credentials
        product: ['auth'],
      });
    });
  }
}
```

---

If you are using **webpack**, then you may call `require.ensure` function to load the required file.

```
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(){        
   require.ensure(['https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js'], require => {
     let Plaid = require('<module_path>');
     Plaid.create({
       // config object
     })
   }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I've made a correction to my question, I use Angular 5 not Angular 2. I tried to add system.js but I can't seem to make it work. I added a script to the index:
  <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  </script>
But the app won't compile and I get an error that the name 'System' cannot be found and the Module was not found at the url.

Comment: @Baron - Did you check with webpack?